# How set a module used by "something"

Tags: linux, fpga

I need your advice.
I want to achieve transactions between my pc and fpga by pcie slot.
I try to install a driver to do that but the driver don't see the fpga.
I run on terminal `$ lspci` and I take this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLpIF.png)

Is there any way to connect xdma module with my fpga manually...??

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the **"Used By"** column of `lsmod` does not mean whether some user-space program is using the module, but only if it is being used by **other kernel modules**. For example if you check the `usb_core` line from the `lsmod` output, you will see that it is being used by a bunch of USB/HID related modules.

The kernel module (or device deriver) is only a way to enable your system to comunicate with the particular piece of hardware. It only exposes its interface so the rest of the kernel (or userspace programs) can interact with it.

You will need for sure some user level software or application that makes use of the interface exposed by the kernel module.

I don't know for your particular case, but the interface that the driver exposes depends on the type of the hardware and the module implementation itself. It may expose some files to `/sysfs`, or add a new syscall (this is very unlikely, but it's a possibility), or make special usage of `ioctl`.

So, you should check for the module documentation, or look for some user-space program that knows how to interface with the driver.

Comment: I try to find a program for that but all the programs that I found, they run on Windows. I can not find something for linux.

Comment: A quick search brought up https://github.com/bmartini/zynq-xdma and https://www.xilinx.com/Attachment/Xilinx_Answer_65444_2016_1.pdf but I'm not sure if that can be of any use for you.

Comment: I have all ready used the Answer_65444 and I have the above problem. The driver don't recognize the fpga. Thanks for your reply anyway.